# java regular expression take next value

Tags: java, regex

here my problem

i have this string that i get value from webservice.....

"2000-07-01 14:29:12","2020-07-01 14:29:12",,"Property Inspection","maryam.com","Bakar","Maryam","915ae8fa7cdb44b3-1368080159272","05/21/2013 07:28:59","05/09/2013 06:15:59","Property Inspection","2","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","05/09/2013","","","","","","05/09/2013","","False","False","False","False","","","","","","","","","","","False","","","False","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","05/09/2013","","","","","","","","","","","05/09/2013","","1.5678106,103.6354891","","",""

currently i manage to split all the data using

```
StringTokenizer stringtokenizer = new StringTokenizer(gabung[rline], ",");
```

but i dont want string value starting from 1st string until the 12th string which are

```
> "2000-07-01 14:29:12","2020-07-01 14:29:12",,"Property
> Inspection","maryam.com","Bakar","Maryam","915ae8fa7cdb44b3-1368080159272","05/21/2013
> 07:28:59","05/09/2013 06:15:59","Property Inspection","2",
```

but i want the value of next after the 12th string..

what i did is using string split and split using ','  and a counter .. to count whether it is the 12th string or not

instead using counter.. do you guys have better solution? i dont understand regex much.

Comment: You have to create a rule to when to take the value. What's the rule gonna be?

Comment: As these data are csv it's probably a lot easier and less error-prone to use a specialized library like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [supercsv](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) - handling csv data correctly is a whole lot harder than it looks at first sight.

Comment: By rule we mean - Do you want the 12th string or the one after "2" or what?

Comment: @dukeling i want after the 12th string... currently i have all.

Comment: I think your problem is that the split will also split a quoted string.

Comment: @Dukeling or should i do counter after 12th string only display string value?

Comment: @LefterisE how to solve the qouted problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you want only the 12th value

**Using `split`:** (very simply, a bit inefficient, but probably not too bad - I wouldn't bother with anything else unless I'm writing production code)

```
System.out.println(str.split(",")[12]);
```

**Using `indexOf`:** (somewhat more complex, way more efficient)

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
   index = str.indexOf(',', index) + 1;
System.out.println(str.substring(index, str.indexOf(',', index)));
```

**Using regex:** (probably more complicated than it's worth)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:[^,]*,){12}([^,]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

### If you want everything from the 12th value

**Using `indexOf`:**

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
   index = str.indexOf(',', index) + 1;
System.out.println(str.substring(index));
```

**Using regex:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:[^,]*,){12}(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

### [Test](http://ideone.com/Catxfx).

Check out [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more on Java regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will match a quoted string followed by an optional comma

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\",?");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
 int count = 0;
 while(m.find()) {
     System.out.println(INPUT.substring(m.start(), m.end());
 }
```

Comment: how to allow "" <--- without any value?

Comment: `[^\"]*` the expression means match any character other than double quote from 0 to n times

Answer (score 0):

If there would always be 94 number of `,` separating each string..You can **split** the input with this regex

```
,(?=(?:[^,]*,){82}[^,]*$)
```

So

```
String[] output = inputString.split(aboveRegex);
output[1];//your required value
```

**OR**

if you are sure about the first 12 strings,you can **match** it with this regex

```
(?:[^,]*,){12}(.*)$//group1 captures your required data
```